# How do I process Authorize.Net payments without a card (using the "card not present" test account)

Tags: php, e-commerce, authorize.net

The card_num field is required but all I have is a card noT present testing account. How exactly do I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be confusing terms here. From their terrifically terrible, unlinkable [knowledge base](http://authorize.net/support/knowledgebase/):

> A **Card Present** Transaction means just that. **The cardholder is physically present along with the card** at the point of purchase. This means that the track data encoded on the magnetic stripe at the back of the credit card can be read by a magnetic stripe reader and sent to the Authorize.Net Card Present System.
>   ...
>   **A Card Not Present transaction is one where the merchant accepts payment information from a cardholder without seeing the plastic card.** These merchants belong to eCommerce, MOTO and Direct Marketing market type.

Unless your vague question implies something completely different, Card Not Present simply means you're an eCommerce merchant. You'll still have to send *something* for the card to be authorized, which is the card number.

There are reserved "fake" test numbers you can use to test transactions. Visa for example uses `4111 1111 1111 1111` if I remember correctly. They're in the documentation somewhere, I just can't find it right now.

Comment: tnx for the ansr and i really think i was confusing terms. sorry because its the first time i'l work with a payment system.:D

Comment: Yes and no.. they are generic terms meaning that the Track1 and Track2 data were not sent along with the transaction. It has everything and nothing to do with eCommerce. That is just an example.